# GWT resourcebundle can't find classpath

Tags: java, gwt, resourcebundle

So I have a GWT project and on the server side I am trying to load a properties file into a resource bundle, but am failing. I keep getting a missing resource exception because it can't locate the file but every option I've tried doesn't work. I've tried placing the `config.properties` file in `war/config/config.properties` as well as `src/config/config.properties` (so 2 copies) and I've tried calling it the following ways

```
TestGWTProject.war.config.config.properties
TestGWTProject.war.config.config
TestGWTProject.src.config.config.properties
TestGWTProject.war.config.config
src.config.config.properties
src.config.config
```

and my current call is this

`ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config");`

yet nothing works. Ideally, I'd like to keep it in the war file, but if it has to stay in src no biggie, but I'd like to just be able to find it at this point. What am i overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your properties in the src folder (as I think you should) you need to give `ResourceBundle` a class-like qualified name, so that when application gets compiled, it can find the properties file in the classes folder.

In my case, for ex., I place them in my source folder, inside a package. Like this:

> src/package/subpackage/subsubpackage/propertiesFile.properties

When I want to load the properties, I use this as the qualified name:

> package.subpackage.subsubpackage.propertiesFile

This is the same way you would give your application a full qualified name for a class. The key here is that the properties file is getting copied to the classes folder inside the WAR. So your mistake was telling the `ResourceBundle` to look into the src folder.

Comment: is there a way I can call it from the WAR file? I figured this case is more ideal as it limits me hunting around the classpath on the deployed app. I marked your answer as correct anyways, thanks!

Comment: I am not sure. I think ResourceBundle requires to have the properties file in the classpath. You would need to load the file manually if you want to pick it from somewhere else(and that will give you other issues likely...) IMO, it is handy to have it in the classpath. You can make a root package called resources (or config) and place them there